# Google Apps Script in VSCode

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm creating my Google Apps Script(GAS) app with VSCode and clasp.

Now, "scriptlets" causes problems in my "index.html"(the picture below).

[image: errors occur in my code]

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Try `<?= datasets ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just my guess from your question. From `new Chart` of your showing script in the image, if you are using [Chart.js](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js), under `type: 'bar'`, the value of `data.datasets` is required to be an array including the objects. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

As sample data, if `datasets` in Google Apps Script side is as follows,

```js
const data = [
  { label: 'sample A', data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)" },
  { label: 'sample B', data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)" },
];
```

how about the following modification?

#### Google Apps Script side:

```js
// Please replace your data.
const data = [
  { label: 'sample A', data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)" },
  { label: 'sample B', data: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1], backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,0,1)" },
];
const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index"); // Please replace your actual HTML filename.
htmlTemplate.datasets = JSON.stringify(data);
const htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate();

// Please use htmlOutput in your script.
```

#### HTML side:

##### From:

```
datasets: [<?!= datasets ?>]
```

##### To:

```
datasets: <?!= datasets ?>
```

- If your `datasets` is like `'{"label":"sample A","data":[1,2,3,4,5],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255,0,0,1)"},{"label":"sample B","data":[5,4,3,2,1],"backgroundColor":"rgba(0,255,0,1)"}'`, I think that you can modify as follows. In this case, I think that you can use your current `datasets: [<?!= datasets ?>]`.

  ```js
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("index"); // Please replace your actual HTML filename.
  htmlTemplate.datasets = '{"label":"sample A","data":[1,2,3,4,5],"backgroundColor":"rgba(255,0,0,1)"},{"label":"sample B","data":[5,4,3,2,1],"backgroundColor":"rgba(0,255,0,1)"}'; // Please replace your data.
  const htmlOutput = htmlTemplate.evaluate();

  // Please use htmlOutput in your script.
  ```

#### Note:

- Unfortunately, I cannot know your value of `datasets` and your whole script from your question. So, when my guess of your question was not correct, can you provide your whole script for correctly replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

#### Reference:

- [HTML Service: Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response. I changed my search word and Googled once again, hit this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238534/make-vscode-syntax-highlighting-accept-google-apps-script-scriptlets -- I'm sorry I didn't make it clear enough.